SendGrid fat jar error: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
According to information found here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java, I should be able to download the sendgrid "fat" jar and use that without needing additional dependancies, but I get this error when starting my Spring application:
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

I have tried older versions and they have the same issue. I have also tried this and see the same error:
curl -L -O https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/releases/download/4.10.2/sendgrid-java.jar
jarsigner -verify sendgrid-java.jar

Output from jarsigner is:
jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Is there a workaround or fix for this?

What is the question?

That's the thing about fat jars. Signing has to be broken as then there's no longer just one signing principal involved. There are several, which makes signing effectively impossible

@aled I guess question would be "How to get rid of this error?". I figured this this was apparent since people posting here usually want to get rid of errors, but I will edit the post....  Perhaps you can remove the downvote?

I didn't downvote the question.

It seems to be a bug in the build of the jar. You should report it to the sendgrid project. Have you tried using a build system for your project instead of the jar, like Maven or Gradle?

Thanks @aled. I am using ant (it's an old project) and manually copying in the fat jar file. I already have some of the dependencies that sendgrid has in my project (apache httpcore, etc.) and I was hoping to use the fat jar instead of reconciling sendgrid dependencies with my other needs. It seems when you use sendgrid via maven it doesn't use the fat jar, but pulls down the deps separately. Makes me think sendgrid doesn't actually support the fat jar. I was kinda hoping sendgrid would be watching StackOverflow and respond... I don't like creating an account to ask a single question :-).

They may or may not be looking at questions but on the other hand [so] is not the right place to report bugs.

Try THIS fat jar

Thanks @g00se. I think that is the same as removing .SF and .DSA files from fat jar. It did resolve the signature error, but now I get a weird error at startup:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/app/tomcat/myapp.9.0.87/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/service/SendGridService.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 35554.
I think I'm gonna bite the bullet and try not using the fat jar.

OK, I'm not sure that new problem is related to the fat jar though. If you've got that jar now I'll delete it?

I got it. Thanks!

@g00se update if you're interested: The BeanDefinitionStoreException was narrowed down to code recipients.stream().map(Email::getEmail).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));. I am using Spring 3.1 in this app and I think it is unaware of this newer code style. I changed it to a for loop and it worked. Continued...

@g00se ...I went back to trying the fat jar. Turns out it is not isolated from other jars in an app. I have overlapping dependencies, so I still have to work that out. After all this, I recommend avoiding the fat jar altogether and pull the separate jars off mvn instead. Also, if you have overlappping dependencies (eg, jackson, httpcore), you might want to skip the web API and use SMTP as mentioned here link. Also also, the dependencies they use are pretty old and have documented vulnerabilities.

Right, I see. They need to do bit more work

Their pom is misconfigured for Shade. For fat jars, signing has to be broken as jarring has to be done again, and it is precisely the jarring phase where signing is done. You can't sign one or more someone else's jar again. This will obviate the problem:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
    <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
    <name>Twilio SendGrid Java helper library</name>
    <version>4.10.2</version>
    <description>This Java module allows you to quickly and easily send emails through Twilio SendGrid using Java.</description>
    <url>https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The MIT License (MIT)</name>
            <url>https://github.com/sendgrid/java-http-client/blob/HEAD/LICENSE</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <properties>
        <jackson.version>2.14.0</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:sendgrid/sendgrid-java.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:sendgrid/sendgrid-java.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>4.10.2</tag>
    </scm>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>release</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.8</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                            <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                            <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <keyname>${gpg.keyname}</keyname>
                                    <passphrase>${gpg.passphrase}</passphrase>
                                    <gpgArguments>
                                        <arg>--pinentry-mode</arg>
                                        <arg>loopback</arg>
                                    </gpgArguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>com.sendgrid</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.sendgrid.helpers.mail</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>com.sendgrid</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                    <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>LICENSE</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.sendgrid</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sendgrid.helpers.mail</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.sendgrid</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>thinkingserious</id>
            <name>Elmer Thomas</name>
            <email>ethomas@twilio.com</email>
            <url>https://sendgrid.com</url>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.28.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
            <version>1.76</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>

